# How do I edit data in a data table that is bound to a combo box without using a datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am using a combo box that is bound to a data table by the primary key. By selecting a value from the dropdown I am able to populate several textboxes in a form. I can easily add a new record to the data table. Occasionally I need to edit an existing record but I cannot discover the "index" of the row corresponding to the selection in the combo box even though I can populate the textboxes. Are there any methods to use with "datarow" to determine what record the "Pointer" is pointing to?  If so perhaps then I could reference that datarow and write new data to the datatable, then update using a dataadapter... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.  You don't need to know the index of the row or the row for that matter.  What you should be doing is:

1. Binding your `DataTable` to a `BindingSource`, which you add in the designer.
2. Binding your `BindingSource` to your `ComboBox` AND your `TextBoxes`.
3. Select records in the `ComboBox` and edit in the `TextBoxes` as you like.
4. When it's time to save, call `EndEdit` on the `BindingSource` to ensure any pending edit is committed to the `DataTable`.
5. Use the same data adapter to save the changes from your `DataTable` as you used to populate it in the first place.

The binding would look something like this:

```
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable

With myComboBox
    .DisplayMember = "DisplayColumn"
    .ValueMember = "PKColumn"
    .DataSource = myBindingSource
End With

myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myBindingSource, "EditColumn")
```

The saving would look something like this:

```
myBindingSource.EndEdit()
myDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable)
```

At no point do you have to care what rows were edited and where they are in the `DataTable` because `Update` will just save all changes.

Comment: Your code works with only one "Exception".  When the existing record uses the same primary key, the constraint throws an exception.  I could use nested "Try's" to jump over the exception. This appears to work, but is there another way to avoid the exception in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying that you're trying to inert records with the same PK as an existing record? You're doing something wrong but, without a clear explanation of what you're doing, I can't tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest that you consider this question closed and post a new question with full details of your current code and actions and a description of exactly what happens.